# Single space in back button doesn't change icon Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an `Xcode` project with a header that I want to change the icon for it from a text to a left arrow,
i'm writing a single space in the `navigationBar` back button text, 
but the icon just disappear it doesn't change it to a left icon
as i want

what am i doing wrong ?

here is what i had befor the change:

[image]

here is what i want to achieve:

[image]

I changed the header text to a single space and I understood it should change it to an arrow:

[image]

[image]

but the result is still just empty header

[image]

here is my hierarchy

[image]

what am i doing wrong ? and how can i change the icon ?

Comment: Because you can't override like that the back button. You are placing it, and only the generated one will have the "<". So the easiest way to do so, is before pushing the ViewController set the `currentVC.title = ""` (or `" "`). This way you should have a "<".

Comment: @Larme can you write it as an answer and give some code example please ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog Login Assistance is your rootViewController?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want text as a back button in your navigation bar, you should act on the `UINavigationItem`'s `backBarButtonItem` of the previous controller.

Apple documentation specifies :

> The backBarButtonItem property of a navigation item reflects the back
>   button you want displayed when the current view controller is just
>   below the topmost view controller. In other words, the back button is
>   not used when the current view controller is topmost.

The default value is nil, and if you set it to a single space " " it will only display the back icon.

In your case you're using a storyboard file, so you can find the UINavigationItem at the same level as the controller's view in the Document Outline.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by setting title to "" of previous view controller from where you push current controller where you want back button icon only. Like:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! VC

.....
.....
.....

self.title = ""
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This solution works but you also set the title displayed on top of the first UIViewController to an empty string, and you might want to have a title on that controller.

Comment: @DamienBannerot, Yes you are right. This can also fix by setting title in `viewWillAppear` method on that view controller. So title will be available when user go back to that screen.